# How to exceute stored procedure without locking the tables?

Tags: stored-procedures, mysql

How to exceute stored procedure without locking the tables in MySQL?

Comment: Insufficient information for meaningful answer. Please reword the question as a real question. We need to know exactly what type of locking is causing a problem or what you think it is? Executing a stored procedure does not lock any tables, unless the procedure does something which causes a table to be locked; please post evidence of the table being locked as well as the source of the stored procedure in question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot set it for a specific Stored Procedure. But for your query, you can set that it should `READ UNCOMMITTED` (equivalent to `NOLOCK` hint in SQLServer).

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/set-transaction.html#isolevel_read-uncommitted